# Tags: ableton and ableton-live

Tags: discussion

Is the reason for both `ableton` and `ableton-live` tags so that people have a place to put Push or Link questions? I don't know of anything anything else that Ableton makes. A lot of the `ableton` tagged questions, from a quick glance, just look like `ableton-live` questions.